# WebSocket++ в многопоточной среде

Tags: c++, многопоточность, websocket, asio

Использую библиотеку [WebSocket++ (0.7)](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp). В исходниках для функции `connection_ptr endpoint::get_con_from_hdl(connection_hdl hdl, lib::error_code & ec)` присутствует замечание:

> NOTE: This method may be called by handler to upgrade its handle to a full connection_ptr. That full connection may then be used safely for the remainder of the handler body. get_con_from_hdl and the resulting connection_ptr are NOT safe to use outside the handler loop.

Хотя просмотрев исходники я так и не понял из-за чего присутствует данное ограничение.

Вопрос: Функция `get_con_from_hdl` используется самой библиотекой в функциях класса `endpoint`, например в `endpoint::send()`. Как в таком случае безопасно вызвать `endpoint::send()` извне *handler loop*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему эта библиотека использует boost asio. Я так понимаю что эту функцию можно вызвать только из потока где запущен handler loop (цикл обработки сообщений). Boost например позволяет его запустить в нескольких потоках.

Comment: Не обязательно boost asio, можно и standalone asio. handler loop для конкретного соединения или что имеется ввиду? При многопоточной обработке извне любого из обработчиков таких как message, open, close, например, как у меня - по срабатыванию таймера неизвесно в том ли мы потоке или в любом другом. Вопрос остается - как отправить данные в нужном потоке?